# Splitting Columns by Number of Characters

Tags: r

I have a column of dates in a data table entered in 6-digit numbers as such: `201401, 201402, 201403, 201412, etc.` where the first 4 digits are the year and second two digits are month.

I'm trying to split that column into two columns, one called "year" and one called "month". Been messing around with `strsplit()` but can't figure out how to get it to do number of characters instead of a string pattern, i.e. split in the middle of the 4th and 5th digit.

Answer (score 12):

Without using any external package, we can do this with `substr`

```
transform(df1, Year = substr(dates, 1, 4), Month = substr(dates, 5, 6))
#    dates Year Month
#1  201401 2014    01
#2  201402 2014    02
#3  201403 2014    03
#4  201412 2014    12
```

We have the option to remove or keep the column.

---

Or with `sub`

```
cbind(df1, read.csv(text=sub('(.{4})(.{2})', "\\1,\\2", df1$dates), header=FALSE))
```

---

Or using some package solutions

```
library(tidyr)
extract(df1, dates, into = c("Year", "Month"), "(.{4})(.{2})", remove=FALSE)
```

---

Or with data.table

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df1)[, tstrsplit(dates, "(?<=.{4})", perl = TRUE)]
```

Answer (score 7):

`tidyr::separate` can take an integer for its `sep` parameter, which will split at a particular location:

```
library(tidyr)

df <- data.frame(date = c(201401, 201402, 201403, 201412))

df %>% separate(date, into = c('year', 'month'), sep = 4)
#>   year month
#> 1 2014    01
#> 2 2014    02
#> 3 2014    03
#> 4 2014    12
```

Note the new columns are character; add `convert = TRUE` to coerce back to numbers.

Comment: This code lists the data frame in the terminal, try using the following to create a new data frame with the split columns df2 <- separate(df, date, into = c('year', 'month'), sep = 4).  Note that in the tidyr package, the order is data, column, new columns,...)

Comment: Well yes, assign it to a variable if you want to keep it.