# how do you split one column in 2 columns in R

Tags: r

I have a data frame like this:

```
V1  V2 V3       V4        V5   V6 V7     V8    V9     V10   V11     V12 V13 V14 V15 V16 V17   V18 V19   V20  V21 Date
1 Thu Jul  7 11:59:18 201611968 9984  0 9973.4 99904 36999.0 40960 24086.3   -   -   -   -  15 0.145   1 0.025 0.17 <NA>
2 Thu Jul  7 11:59:38 201611968 9984  0 9973.4 99904 39544.0 40960 24086.3   -   -   -   -  15 0.145   1 0.025 0.17 <NA>
```

I need to split column V5 into two columns. 2016 part is the year and I need to put that into another column itself? Any ideas how I could do this?

Comment: Literally just asked: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38252823/splitting-columns-by-number-of-characters/38252907

Comment: With tidyr: `df %>% separate(V5, into = c('year', 'the_rest'), sep = 4)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `sub` to create a delimiter (`,`) between the 4th and 5th character in 'V5', use `read.csv` to read it as data.frame and `cbind` with the original dataset.

```
cbind(df1, read.csv(text=sub('(.{4})(.*)', "\\1,\\2", df1$V5), header=FALSE))
```